# Can an NP-Complete problem be reduced to an NP problem?

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np

All NP problems can be reduced to NP-Complete problems, can an NP-Complete problem be reduced to a NP problem (non complete)?

Comment: Are you asking whether, for a given NP-complete problem $NP_C$ there exists any problem $NP_x \in NP, NP_x \ne NP_C$ such that $NP_C$ can be reduced to $NP_x$? That would make $NP_C$ NP-complete, too. And yes, there is more than one NP-complete problem. (Or no, such an $NP_x$ is *not* non-complete.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An NP-complete problem is in NP, by definition. No reduction needed.

Comment: Okay I feel really dumb now! Thanks for making it clear

Comment: @PedroPapel Welcome to [CS.SE]! please consider accepting this as the answer if it helped you, thank you.